# Run some functions parallel in an interval async?

Tags: c#, .net, timer, thread-safety

I have a Timer and Im calling some functions in an interval. Right now I have something like this:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;
private int sync;

void Start()
{
  timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
  timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Elapsed);
  timer.Enabled = true;
}

void Elapsed(object s, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  if (System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sync, 1, 0) == 0)
  {
    Parallel.Invoke( () => Function1(), () => Function2(), () => Function3(),
                     () => Function4() );
  }
  sync = 0;
}
```

This is not bad. I can start the functions parallel AND one function cannot run 2+ times, just once (this is how I want it). The problem is: lets say `function4()` takes longer then my `interval`, so the other functions have to wait too. If I remove the `sync` there, the other functions wont wait BUT another `function4()` call could start in another thread - and I dont want that one functions is running twice. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to keep track of each function individually so you have control on which functions you can initiate right away and which ones you need to wait on e.g.

```
private AutoResetEvent f1 = new AutoResetEvent(true);
private AutoResetEvent f2 = new AutoResetEvent(true);
...

void Elapsed(object s, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Parallel.Invoke(() => { f1.WaitOne(); Function1(); f1.Set(); },
                    () => { f2.WaitOne(); Function2(); f2.Set(); }
                    ...
    ...
}
```

Something like this would block any functions that are already executing and allow other ones to start which aren't.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure I did 100% understand this :) But I will try to implement this one.

Comment: @silla Only one call to `FunctionX` can happen at any one time, but it shouldn't block other calls. So basically what happens is you initiate a parallel call for all 4 functions, we block execution of `FunctionX` if it's already running via `WaitOne`. Once `FunctionX` is finished in another thread it calls `Set` which then releases the block and allows the other thread to execute `FunctionX`.

Comment: Im confused but are you sure I have to use new AutoResetEvent(false); instead of new AutoResetEvent(true);? Because if I use false none of the function is running, but with true they are.

Comment: @silla sorry you are correct they should be defaulting to `true`, that was my mistake.

Comment: ok! Then every thing is working and fine :) Thank you again, at the end it was not that hard.